# Two continuous functions such that $f(z)^2=g(z)=1-z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find an open connected set $G\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and two continuous functions $f,g$ defined on $G$ such that $f(z)^2=g(z)^2=1-z^2$. Can you make $G$ maximal? Are $f$ and $g$ analytic?

Well. If we define $G$ to be the set of all $z$ such that $1-z^2$ has positive real part and $\log$ is the principal branch and $f(z)=\exp\left(\dfrac 12\log(1-z^2)\right)=-g(z)$, that would do the work and clearly they're analytics.

But what about the maximality of $G$? Is that set maximal?